# VBA Access-Word interop problem: I cannot open more then 1 Word doc from Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, office-interop

In Access I have a table for records having different fields and in particular an OLE Object for Word ".docx" documents. A form shows data (a BoundObjectFrame the OLE Word documents).
Actually, there are 2 tables and 2 forms because the Word documents (based on the same template ".dotm") are of two kinds.

The Word template on which the documents are based has to do a lot of work when a saved file is opened (in ThisDocument.Document_Open). But I was almost always receiving an error when I was opening them in the usual way (double click or contextual menu on the BoundObjectFrame) and sometimes even just in loading the records in the form. The cause of the problem seemed to be a reference of the ActiveDocument not found by Word. I tried to explain the problem in [this thread](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/activedocument-doesnt-exist-only-when-ole-word-document-is-opened-from-an-access-form.327196/).

So since I was always able to open the Word files with my code, I decided to repurpose both contextual menu and double click over BoundObjectFrame, and use the simple following code:

```
  Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
...
  Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  With objWordApp
      .Visible = True
      .Activate
      .Documents.Open sMyFileName
  End With
  Set objWordApp = Nothing
...
```

Now when I open a file everything is fine, but if I try to open a second one, I receive an error (and more often it is a file from the other form, kind file but same template).

I was receiving the following error, when objWordApp.Activate was not set and .visible was after the open.
[image]

Now, with the code posted earlier I get:
[image]

But both in Word and Access the folder where the files are saved is trusted.

I don't know if I was clear.
Do you have any suggestions,
Thanks, Lauro

Comment: Should provide error messages as English text in your question, not images. I tested your code and it works for me. Opens file each time code runs.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that this is the cause of your issues but you're use of `Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")` creates a new instance of Word each time. `CreateObject` should only be used as a fallback when `GetObject` fails, i.e. you should only create a new instance if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: Message translation: Microsoft Office has identified a potential security issue. Microsoft has blocked the execution of macros because the source of the file is not trusted

Comment: The path in the message is not mine, but I think a temporary one. The files are saved in folder trusted locations (with subfolders)

Comment: to create a reference to a word application I used one of the following three manner, with the same results: 1) Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application"); 2) On Error Resume Next :  Set objWordApp = GetObject("Word.Application") :  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") :  On Error GoTo 0; Set objWordApp = New Word.Application

Comment: The error never happens if no other instances of Word are opened; It happens generally at the third document from the same Form, and at the second from the other Form.

Comment: I repeat the folders's files are trusted. The message remind the one you receive when you download a file from Internet

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be with the code inside the template Document_open since I inserted as first line Exit Sub and the result is the same

Comment: Just a suggestion, nothing more: have a look at Word.Application.Options and see if any of them are relevant. (I didn't think so, but there are some options to do with "network" files such as .LocalnetworkFile - worth checking, IMO)

Comment: Thank Jonsson for the suggestion, I'm out now but I will check next days